# Irreducible polynomial of degree 5 over the field of 2 elements has distinct roots in any algebraic closure of the field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Any irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_2[x] $ of degree $5$ has distinct roots in any algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_2$.
Here $\mathbb F_2$ is the $2$ elements field.

My logic is  we know that $\mathbb F_2 $ is a perfect field, hence every algebraic extension is separable, so every algebraic closure is separable,hence the polynomial has distinct roots.

Is my answer right ? Any insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

Without knowing that finite fields are perfect, the case at hand can be shown directly:

Let $f\in\Bbb F_2[x]$  be irreducible of degree $5$ and assume $f$ has some multiple root $\alpha$ in $\overline{\Bbb F_2}$.
Then 
$$f(x) = x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+1.$$
with $a_i\in\Bbb F_2$.
Note that $f(x+1)=x^5+(a_4+1)x^4+\ldots$ is also irreducible of degree $5$ and has $\alpha+1$ as multiple root in $\overline{\Bbb F_2}$.
Therefore,  we may assume wlog. that $a_4=0$.

Note that the multiple root $\alpha$ is also a root of the formal derivative $f'(x)= x^4+a_3x^3+a_1x$ and therefore also of
$g(x)=f(x)-xf'(x)=a_2x^2+1$.

As $g(\alpha)=0$, we cannot have $a_2=0$. But then $g(x)=(x+1)^2$ and we conclude $\alpha=1$, contradicting irreducibility of $f$.