# Question regarding algebraic closure of$ \mathbb{F_2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Let $\mathbb{F_2} $ be the finite field of order $2$. Then
>   which of the following statements are true?
>
> $1.$ $\mathbb{F_2} [x]$ has only finitely many irreducible
>    elements.
>
> $2.$ $\mathbb{F_2} [x]$ has exactly one irreducible polynomial
>    of degree $2.$
>
> $3.$$\mathbb{F_2} [x]/<x^2+1>$
>    is a finite dimensional
>    vector space over .
>
> $4.$ Any irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F_2} [x]$ of
>    degree $5$ has distinct roots in any algebraic
>    closure of $\mathbb{F_2}$

My attempt:

- option 1)  will True  take $f(x) = x^2+x+1$
- option $2)$ will false  because  number   irreducible polynomail of degree $2 = \frac{p^2-p}{p-1} = 2$
- option  $3)$  will true   dimension will be  $4$
- option $4$  i  don't  have any hints  to tackle this  option

any  hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: How does your argument prove that 1) is true?

Comment: @Arthur there is one irreducible elment that is $ x^2 +x+ 1$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Comment: That is one. Are there more?

Comment: i have  to searched  @Arthur.. im  looking

Comment: Q: True or false: there are only finitely many natural numbers. A: True, $1$ is a natural number. Q: How does that prove that there are only finitely many natural numbers? A: There is one natural number, $1$. Q: What about $2$, and $3$, and $4$, and...

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ is a simple extension of $\mathbb F_{2}$ for each $n$? Then, the minimal polynomial of the generator must be irreducible and of order $n$, so we have, for each natural number, an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb F_2$ of that degree. Hence, we get infinitely many irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thanks

Comment: @jasmine You are welcome. Also, the answer below takes care of everything else.

Comment: In 3rd option $(x^2+1)$ is not prime ideal(as it is reducible polynomial) then how this set will be set of linear polynomials will come, set of linear polynomials will be an infinite set as well, any other reasons for this to become vectorspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ has an irreducible element of degree $n$ for every $n$, so certainly infinitely many.

But it only has one of degree $2$: there are only $4$ candidates to check and only $x^2 +x +1$ is irreducible.

$\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ is essentially the set of linear polynomials (we identify $x^2$ with $1$), which is a vector space of dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

For 4. yes, see [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424011/irreducible-polynomial-of-degree-5-over-the-field-of-2-elements-has-distinct-roots)

Comment: thanks u @Henno sir   can u give   any hints  of option  $4$

Comment: In 3rd option $(x^2+1)$ is not prime ideal(as it is reducible polynomial) then how this set will be set of linear polynomials will come

Comment: @sabeelmsk It is generated by the classes of $1$ and $x$, which form a base. It's just the set $\{1,x,1+x,0\}$ which forms a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since every finite field is a perfect field and every finite field extension over a perfect field is also perfect so $F_2[X]$ is perfect as it is a finite field extension over $F_2$ which is also finite. Now we know that every irreducible polynomial over a perfect field has distinct roots, therefore option 4 is correct.